# not able to use firebase integration in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase in flutter application after updating the libraries to the latest version.
Below is the code which was previously used but now I am facing error

CODE

```
void main() {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true).then((_) {
    print("Timestamps enabled in snapshots\n");
  }, onError: (_) {
    print("Error enabling timestamps in snapshots\n");
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

ERROR

```
error: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.
```

when I am implementing the above code I get the error, please help me to resolve this

Comment: As far as I know, the `timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` setting is non longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code that should fix it.

```
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Initialize the Firebase instance before runApp(MyApp());

```
void main() async{

     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
     //Before running App During load time initialize firebase instance.

     runApp(MyApp());
}
```